# Mouse event doesn't trigger in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

The class ".folders" doesn't trigger any events. Actually, all the classes within ".data" class doesn't trigger the mouse events. I have tried with ".search" class and it worked fine.

[image]

Comment: please add all relevant code to OP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delegate your event if they are dynamically added

```
$('.data').on('click','.folders',function(){
 //click event
});
```

else make sure you element are visible on the page and not overlapping with any existing divs

Comment: hi, thanks.
it is working now. yes it is dynamically created.